# Is there any way to show the current saved state with meteor.js autoform package?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-autoform

I'm using meteor.js with the aldeed:autoform package with its autosave feature and I'm trying to think of a way to show when the form is saving and when all the data has been saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since autoforms abstracts away the call to save, you can't use the callback, so you'll have to use `observeChanges` to listen to a change to that value, or hack into autoforms a little bit. Honestly, if you're going to go this route, you're past the proof of concept phase & you might (definitely) want to consider rolling your own forms because you've outgrown autoforms.

Let's say you've got a span below your field like: `<span class="just-saved">Saved!</span>`

Here's an example callback (from an input change event):

```
function (err, res) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      var $justSaved = $(t.find('.just-saved'));
      $justSaved.addClass('saving');
      setTimeout(function () {
        $justSaved.removeClass('saving');
      }, 1500);
```

If you were going to do this from a `changed` callback, you'd just change the `find` to something like (`input[name="user.$.phoneNumber"]`) & grab the sibling. Here's an example of what the code above will get you:

[image: Example]

Comment: Great answer thank you, could you explain the observe change bit a little more?  I plan to upgrade m autoform stuff to use a Meteor.nethod as and when I need to , are you saying I should do that in the callback of the method?  or the callback of the Meteor.call ?

Comment: Once the doc changes, the modification is written to the oplog, and your client will be watching that oplog for changes. The changed callback includes the fields that changed. So all you need to do is lookup the input that shows the field. See the docs here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes
Without autoforms, you'll want to do it in the callback of the `Meteor.call`

Comment: Great answer Thank you!  I have marked it correct but it would be good to add your comments about the oplog and observe changes to the body of your answer.